# CucumberOptions "strict" is undefined

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-serenity

I have some manual test cases in which I don't want to define a cucumber step (whats the point as it's not going to be automated). I found I could use the option within @CucumberOptions called "strict" and set this to false so Cucumber would go over undefined steps without throwing an error. However, it seems that this option is no longer available. What should be used instead?

I am using the Serenity, so I am using the CucumberWithSerenity runner class.

[image]

[image]

Comment: `I found I could use the option` where did you find that?

Comment: [A discussion about manual test cases and undefined steps on Serenity github] (https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-core/issues/2013) 

[This article] (https://www.programsbuzz.com/article/what-strict-cucumber)

Comment: Not sure why the formatting isn't working in the above comment

Comment: I think because it is not started with `htttp` and you have a whitespace between `[]` and `()`. Like this won't work [article](www.programsbuzz.com/article/what-strict-cucumber). But this has to work fine [article](https://www.programsbuzz.com/article/what-strict-cucumber)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strict` has been decommissioned starting from Cucumber `7.0.0`. As per [this discussion](https://github.com/cucumber/common/issues/714) if you have some WIP scenarios it is recommended to tag them appropriately and exclude from the run.

For example:

```
Feature: blah

  Scenario: my defined scenario

    Given defined step

  @wip
  Scenario: my undefined scenario

    Given undefined step
```

Then your runner would look like:

```java
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(tags = "not(@wip)")
public class Runner {
}
```